# How can I find out whether I have a blot on my HR record?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, human-resources, performance-reviews

About a year ago, I was laid off from the university I worked for, after the division I was in was cut due to the director's departure. Since then, I have applied for many jobs there, and never even get rejection letters. Once I did get a phone interview that went very well, but I never heard anything. After a couple of weeks, I emailed both the assistant who interviewed me and the project PI, but neither got back. After two more weeks, I left phone messages, and still nothing.

A couple of months ago, I called the person who was my previous director's boss and asked if there was any kind of reason this might be happening. He said he checked my HR record and saw only good evaluations.

A few weeks ago, I directly contacted a PI about a posted position and was called in for an interview. Over a week ago, I received an email from the PI that my references had great things to say about me, and they were working with HR to write me an offer. After a week went by, I politely pinged - two days have passed since then and I've heard nothing.

It seems like even when someone at the university wants to hire me, they run into a hitch with HR that they won't even respond about. I'm very concerned that there is some skull-and-crossbones symbol or red alarm buzzer that turns on when HR types my name into the system.

I've considered contacting HR directly, but then I also wonder if I should be consulting a lawyer first.

How can I find out if there is some kind of note on my HR record that says "forget this guy, and don't even respond?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent recruiters from "ghosting" on me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113953/how-do-i-prevent-recruiters-from-ghosting-on-me)

Comment: I also think the above linked question might be highly related, or even perhaps a duplicate of your situation (specially the no contacting part), if you want to consider it.

Comment: What exactly do you hope to accomplish by calling HR? The PI said you have a good standing with HR, so I'm unsure what you would hope in getting. My advice is to take your resume and get a second opinion on your interviewing skills.

Comment: @DarkCygnus -- good point. I edited the question.

Comment: Dan--the problem is that any time someone actually looks like they might be interested in me--even to the point of telling me they are writing an offer--I never hear from them again, and they don't respond to further attempts at communication.

Comment: @abalter How did you make it that your HR record is at fault? Did you do anything while in your previous position? The one PI individual even said your HR record is great. So it is obviously something else that is going wrong.

Comment: @DarkCygnus -- I read through that other question, and here is what I think is different: 1) I'm not going through recruiters, and 2) In one case I had a person specifically say "we are writing you an offer" before stopping to respond, and 3) This is all at the same company, where I have already been an employee. Thus there could actually be a memo or note on my HR record with that company.

Comment: @Dan -- I have no idea. Maybe a note or memo they only show a PI when they are ready to make an offer?

Comment: @abalter I find that a bit unbelievable that there would a secret note on it while the PI said your record is good. The problem here is you're fishing in a bucket with no fish next to a huge pond and wondering what is going on wrong.

Comment: Not hearing something in just over a week is not very long, particularly in summer.

Comment: Do you have a college degree? If you meet the qualifications, but don't have enough prestige companies won't respond to you at all. That actually happened with one department at the company I'm at now. Jokes on them though, I make more than they could pay me doing something else here.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I find out if there is some kind of note on my HR record that says "forget this guy, and don't even respond?"

You can't.

At least not without pulling strings or somehow managing for someone to leak this information, but that I doubt would be legal or ethical. Also, asking them directly is out of the question, as it could further harm you plus they might not have the clearance to disclose that information.

I suggest you try searching for jobs elsewhere, otherwise you might find yourself stuck in a loop if you keep trying with this university.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get a friend to call, doing a mock "verification of employment" call, you can see how HR is referring to you.

There are plenty of website that show how to make that call [LIKE THIS ONE](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-employment-verification-calls-19094.html)

Have a friend make the call and see what happens.  IF they're being less than professional in that call, see a lawyer.

Comment: As I read the question, OP is trying to apply to the *same* university, so I'm not sure this is applicable.

Comment: @Dukeling IF they're doing this internally, there is no reason to expect that they're not doing it to external inquiries as well.

Comment: There's a big difference between bad-mouthing a former employee and simply deciding not to rehire someone you laid off. The latter sounds perfectly reasonable and legal and could theoretically even just be standard application rejections that have nothing to do with any sort of black mark.

Comment: @Dukeling plenty of room for another answer if you disagree....

Answer (score 2):

Where are you located? Check your local data protection laws. If you were in the UK for example, you could simply request a copy of any data they have on you.